# How to I make an h3 stay in a specific location?

Tags: javascript, css, styling

I'm trying to figure out how to set this `<h3>` to a specific spot so it doesn't move when items are added to the bag (see screenshots below). Currently I have the `<h3>` and the "Remove all" button in a flex container, so they are displayed next to each other. I'm a newbie to CSS so if anyone has any better suggestions, please let me know!

Basically I would like it so the "Your Bag" will stay where it is in the second photo, instead of sitting super close to the button and moving around depending on the length of the title of the item being added. The list of items that get added below are in a `<div>` tag, and the entirety of the page is in another flex container so the "search for a device"  is on the left, and "your bag"  is on the right.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try giving `float:right` to your `h3` tag

```
h3 {
 float: right;
}
```

or you can use `position: absolute` and give *top* and *right* positions.

```
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  right:30px;
}
```